# Should I be worried about a possible threat?

Tags: security, clamav

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10. I use Clamav and have scanned my system regularly for infections. Today it picked up a potential threat 
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rdoc/generator/template/darkfish/js/thickbox-compressed.js.
Ubuntu is my only operating system installed. Clamav was not able to delete or quarantine the file.
Should i be concerned or is this a false positive? I have scanned the same file multiple times and it picks it up as a threat each time. Also i tried googling the issue before posting and found no information.

A point I forgot to mention, clamav picks it up as PUA.script.packed-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That file seems to belong to package `libruby1.9.1`, which should be installed when you installed Ruby.

If that package comes from the default repositories I guess that warning should be nothing to you worry about. If it comes from a PPA then you should take a closer look.

To see from where the package comes you can use `apt-cache`. From my system:

```
$ apt-cache policy libruby1.9.1
libruby1.9.1:
  Installed: (none)  <-- This shows the installed version (not installed on my case)
  Candidate: 1.9.3.0-1ubuntu2.5
  Version table:
     1.9.3.0-1ubuntu2.5 0
        500 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
     1.9.3.0-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

Also consider checking that file in an online scanner like [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com). If only clamav marks it as a potencially threath probably it is a false positive.

Comment: apt-cache policy libruby1.9.1
libruby1.9.1:
  Installed: 1.9.3.194-1ubuntu1.3
  Candidate: 1.9.3.194-1ubuntu1.3
  Version table:
 *** 1.9.3.194-1ubuntu1.3 0
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/main i386 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.9.3.194-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main i386 Packages
forgive me for being new, i dont know what that info really means. I ran it through virustotal though and it said it was clean.

Comment: You can ignore it then, it's everything ok.

Answer (score 1):

According to a [similar post elsewhere](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1429026), `PUA` stands for "Potentially Unwanted Application" and the `script.packed` "usually means it was packed using something which causes AV alerts due to the method used to package the software for install".

It goes on and says that

> Hundreds of small developers get the laughable "you gave my PC a virus email" simply because they decide to use a packer to build their install.

As another answer here indicates, if you got the packages installed from repositories, probably this is also a false positive.

EDIT: For websites at least, [here](http://antivirus-alarm.ru/proverka/?url=www.volagri.ru%2F) and [here](http://www.rockettheme.com/forum/index.php?f=92&t=64285&rb_v=viewtopic), it has been ruled out as a false positive, but you can always upload the file to a service such as [VirScan.org](http://f.virscan.org/thickbox-compressed.js.html) for a check with multiple antivirus engines.